# Баг интерфейса в Sublime Text 3 | *REPL* [python]

Tags: python, sublime-text

Как исправить это? В некоторых случаях таких розовых косяков бывает больше, что не позволяет нормально читать трэйсбек.
Как я понимаю редактор понимает первые две одинарных кавычки как string и происходит путаница
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выключите подсветку синтаксиса в менюшке внизу справа

Comment: Возможно, придется отредактировать саму тему. Я попробовал с помощью этого пакета https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorSchemeEditor - все получилось. Минус в том, что подсветку при такой же ошибке в коде вы потом не увидите.